# Using Postscript or PCL to split a print job into multiple print jobs?

Tags: printing, postscript

We have a Ricoh PRO 8220 enterprise printer that offsets each print job in the stacking tray. I want to use this to our advantage as we have been manually sorting out documents.

We have the ability to add either Postscript or PCL code into our documents, is there a snippet we could add to the end of our documents to trick our printer/system into thinking it's a separate print job?

Comment: For PCL you could use the Universal Exit Language string That's ESC (0x1B) followed by %12345X Reccomendation is to use both printer reset and UEL together printer reset is ESC (0x1B) E. PostScript isn't so easy, PostScript is a programming language, and its trickier to modify a program without breaking it. You **might** be able to insert a control-D (0x04, or EOT), which might work, but no real promises. It might also have unexpected side effects in PostScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll Want too looking in using PJL (Printer Job Language) Code which is used as an outer shell language to other PDLs (Printer Description Language) such as PCL (Printer Control Language) or PostScript. You can find an older reference guide at the following link :
https://www2.ricoh-ap.com/ridp/indexnormaldownload.aspx

The exact reference manual I will be referencing is: PJLLanguageSpecification_2_V3160.pdf

As mentioned in a previous comment, You'll need to use the UEL (Universal Exit Command : "\x1B%-12345X") as well as the "@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE =  \r\n" command too switch between languages and commands. You can also Nest PJL jobs if required. Note the the UEL resets the printer too default power settings (i.e. if you had just powered on the printered) so using "@PJL SET" only affects the current "JOB" while "@PJL DEFAULT" overrides the default settings. Using "@PJL INITIALIZE" you should be able too restore your printer back too manufacturer settings. Any Non-standardized/PJL commands that the printer does not understand should be ignored by the internal software causing no adverse affects other than the command not being executed.

To specify the "OUTBIN" you'll need too use "@PJL SET OUTBIN = [option]"

Where [option] can be the following (as per the manual):

- INNER
- LOWER
- OPTIONALOUTPUTBIN1
- OPTIONALOUTPUTBIN2
- OPTIONALOUTPUTBIN3
- OPTIONALOUTPUTBIN4
- OPTIONALOUTPUTBIN5
- OPTIONALOUTPUTBIN6
- OPTIONALOUTPUTBIN7
- OPTIONALOUTPUTBIN8
- OPTIONALOUTPUTBIN9
- OPTIONALOUTPUTBIN10
- FINISHERSHIFT
- FINISHERPROOF
- FINISHERBOOKLET
- MANUAL
- SEQUENTIALSTACK
- UPPER
- RINGSTACKER
- FOLDPROOF
- LOADINGTRAY

Your overall Print job should follow this general format:

```
<ESC>%-12345X@PJL<CR><LF>
@PJL JOB NAME = "RICOH Test Job" <CR><LF>
@PJL SET ORIENTATION = PORTAIT <CR><LF>
@PJL SET QTY = 1 <CR><LF>
@PJL SET DUPLEX = ON <CR><LF>
@PJL SET RESOLUTION = 600 <CR><LF>
@PJL SET OUTBIN = LOWER <CR><LF>
@PJL COMMENT START PCL JOB <CR><LF>
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PCL <CR><LF>
<ESC>.... PCL CODE .... <ESC>%-12345X@PJL <CR><LF>
@PJL EOJ <CR><LF>
<ESC>%-12345X
```

Some additional notes you might find useful:

1. Use QTY to specify number of Collated copies & COPIES for uncollated copies.
2. The main supported PDL languages include, PCL,POSTSCRIPT and PDF (others)
3. The UEL must be followed directly with a PJL command (@PJL  is an empty command , i.e no action command), except for the last instance which signifies the end of a the print job document.
4. The  , cartridge return "\r" is optional the , Line feed "\n" is REQUIRED.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above document from Ricoh seems to be unavailable now.  However, there is a generic HP specification available [here](https://developers.hp.com/system/files/attachments/PJLReference%282003%29_0.pdf) - or from the Internet Archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230605172357/https://developers.hp.com/system/files/attachments/PJLReference(2003)_0.pdf).